# the_content() is not displaying any content

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am having some problems trying to display content from WordPress. the_title() works just fine, but the_content() is always empty even though there is content in WordPress. And yes the_content() is inside a loop. I still can't figure out why it's always empty.

```
<?php if( get_the_post_thumbnail() ):?>
<?php $backgroundImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src(
        get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full'); ?>
    <div class="img-container" style="background: linear-gradient(#1abc9c, transparent 80%),url('<?php echo 
    $backgroundImg[0]; ?>') no-repeat; background-size: cover;">

        <div class ="text-wrapper">
            <h1 class="single-blog-title"><?php the_title();?></h1>
            <h3 class="single-blog-subtitle"><?php the_secondary_title(); ?></h3>
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <div>

        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<div id="content" class="site-content">
    <div class ="single-blog-content">
        <?php if( have_posts() ): while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
            <p class="blog-author">by <?php the_field('author'); ?></p>
            <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
            <div>
                <?php the_content();?>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should try to disable your plugins one by one in case one of them causes it. Also, is this the single page of a custom post type ? What did you use to create the post type ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to put the content inside loop

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: But the_content() seems to be inside the loop. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I found the `$post->post_content` to contain the content I required; however it isn't filtered so you will need to apply the `the_content` filter to apply HTML formatting:

```
<?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

```
<div class="publication-info">
    <?php printf("<h2>%s</h2>", get_the_title() ); ?>
    <div class="publication-meta publication-credit"><?php the_publication_credit(); ?></div>
    <div class="publication-meta publication-date"><?php the_publication_date(); ?></div><br />
    <div class="publication-blurb" style="font-family:sans-serif;"><?php echo $post->post_content; // the_content() doesn't work. Why not? ?></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code `<?php the_field('author'); ?>` with `<?php the_author(); ?>`
This function `the_field('author');` is the culprit.
Please remove or replace the code. 
Then next function should work.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this The Only Add Below code add in your top of file

```
<?php the_post(); ?><?php if( get_the_post_thumbnail() ):?>
```